# How can I slice variadic template parameters and use them?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I'm quite new to template metaprogramming. This is what I wanted to do.

```
template <typename... Args>
void to_be_async_func(Args&&... args)
{
   //want to use args[0...N-2] to invoke a function call
   //and args[N-1(last)] to use a handler function after the prior call.
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    to_be_async_func(a, b, [](int res)
    {
       //do something with the result
       //any Callable can be passed
    });
}
```

Initially I tried like

```cpp
template<typename... Args, typename Callable>
void to_be_async_func(Args&&... args, Callable op)
{

}
```

However in this case "Callable" should have default value to be used like that.
In my opinion, some kind of helper template struct might do this.
If this thing is possible, could you please show me the way?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
I've also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685810/split-parameter-pack-in-0-n-1-and-nth-element) and tried as instructed.
It worked. But as stated in the text, I want to know if there's a more standard way to achieve this.

Comment: Why cannot you change signature of `to_be_async_func` to use `Callable` as the 1st argument?

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for your reply. Obviously that could be an option. But I wanted to make it more like "easy-to-use, easy to read" function call. To me, it makes more sense if Callable is the last argument. (especially when Callable is a lambda expression.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::index_sequence` seems the way to go:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
void to_be_async_func_first(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename... Args>
void to_be_async_func_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&&... args)
{
    auto&& args_tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    to_be_async_func_first(std::get<sizeof...(Args) - 1>(args_tuple),
                           std::get<Is>(args_tuple)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void to_be_async_func(Args&&... args)
{
    to_be_async_func_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - 1>(),
                          std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: It truly does !! I tried this way and it worked. I'll look into the c++ language features being used in this code. Thank you so so much for your help.